# Multiple canvases causes browser re-paint in `requestAnimationFrame`

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, repaint

I am investigating painting issues in one of my rendering app. I created a simple version of my problem to understand why, with two canvases, a browser re-paint occurs on every frame. The sample only uses two canvases, and 2D contexts (no WebGL for this sample).

I have an HTML page, setup as follows:

```
+----------------------------+
|                            |
|          CANVAS 1          |
|                            |
|                            |
+----------------------------+
|          | 
| CANVAS 2 | 
|__________|
```

The code I am profiling for this example is the following:

```js
window.onload = init;

const image = document.getElementById('source');
const viewer = { canvas: null, context: null };
const thumbnail = { canvas: null, context: null };

function init() {
    viewer.canvas = document.getElementById('viewer');
    viewer.canvas.width = viewer.canvas.clientWidth;
    viewer.canvas.height = viewer.canvas.clientHeight;
    viewer.context = viewer.canvas.getContext('2d', { alpha: false });

    thumbnail.canvas = document.getElementById('thumbnail');
    thumbnail.canvas.width = thumbnail.canvas.clientWidth;
    thumbnail.canvas.height = thumbnail.canvas.clientHeight;
    thumbnail.context = thumbnail.canvas.getContext('2d', { alpha: false });

    animate();
}

function animate() {
    viewer.context.clearRect(0, 0, viewer.canvas.width, viewer.canvas.height);
    viewer.context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, viewer.canvas.width, viewer.canvas.height);

    thumbnail.context.clearRect(0, 0, thumbnail.canvas.width, thumbnail.canvas.height);
    thumbnail.context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, thumbnail.canvas.width, thumbnail.canvas.height);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```css
.body {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: initial;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.second {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 80%;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <img
        style="display: none;"
        id="source"
        src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg"
        width="300"
        height="227"
    >
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="viewer"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="container second">
        <canvas id="thumbnail"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what the Chrome profiler outputs:

[image: Profiler: Massive Repaint]

As you can see, after each `requestAnimationFrame`, a repaint happens. Here, it's around 0.4ms, which is "ok", but in a real app this can go around 10ms, which is obviously not ok at all, as a frame has a budget of 16ms.

Now let's say I change the width of the `.second` CSS class to:

```
.second {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
}
```

The page will render as expected, without any excessive re-paint:

[image: Profiler: No Repaint]

There is obviously something about the browser re-paint mechanism I am not aware of. If someone has a hint about what's happening here, it would be awesome to share it with me.

Comment: So you are saying that even here in the StackSnippet® you can reproduce this issue? For me on Chrome 75 on macOs, each Paint takes about 0.4ms  too but each frame's stack takes only about 2ms (i.e nothing to worry about, the developer tools eat more than that). I would rather investigate what takes the remain 20ms of your rAF task that is not defined in your profiler's graph.

Comment: I run on Chrome 75 too, Windows 10.
There souldn't be any re-paint, that's what I am saying. Also, here it's 0.4, but imagine when I have 5 canvases, that goes up quickly. In one of my app, I blit webgl frames to multiple canvases, and I get re-paints that go between 5 and 20ms.

Comment: Why shoudln't you get any repaint? You did paint on the canvas. There should obviously be a new paint operation. Or are you expecting the browser to know before hand it won't have to repaint because that's the same graphics that are to be paint, and this without painting it? Glad they don't store and compare every graphics' ImageData in search of diffs before painting to screen, that would take eternities.

Comment: If it really needed a repaint, why is the second example not doing it? And run in less than 2ms. It only needs a composite operation

Comment: Because there is something else going on? Once again, what is suspect in your first screenshot is this long task for nothing. Inspect this. The paint operation is just normal. As to your second screenshot, it's simply unreadable from here.

Comment: Yes, because the goal of that screenshot was to simply show that no crazy repaint is  happening in the graph, and that's easy to see. The entire goal of my question is exactly your point: "Because there is something else going on?". How, changing only the witdth of two **non-overlapping div** can create such a difference? That's the real answer I am looking for.

Comment: I ran both versions in a fiddle and the difference is that one is transferred to the GPU while the other is using software rendering. They probably trigger this for canvases (as in paint area, not necessarily the HTMLElement) bigger than a certain area. However, there is no big win for me with 0.6ms painting for the GPU rendering ;-)

Comment: The win can be really important, example here:
https://imgur.com/ngKmDYU
2 ms WebGL rendering, 4-6ms software painting. With the same canvases size.

Comment: no guarantee since it's up to the browser but I know in Chrome at some point 2d canvas's under a certain size are software rendered since for many apps the overhead of communicating with the GPU was net loss.

Comment: I guess I can't count on that then. Maybe then I will need to minimize the number of canvases